# Processing Modeller manual / use-case for Multiple Input and Model Variables

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

Is there a decent manual/examples available somewhere for the Processing Modeller?

Official [help](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html) is very barebones and doesn't explain the different inputs/model variables.

Specifically I am interested in a use-case for: Multiple Input and Model Variables.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple inputs? Can you show us?

Comment: Processing Modeler → Inputs → Multiple Input

https://imgur.com/Jp2jYj0

Comment: @PavelDiptan - First thing that comes to mind is when you want to merge multiple files into one.